# Computer becomes very slow (permanently) after running a bunch of apps

Tags: windows-xp, lag

My computer with Windows XP installed becomes very slow after I ran some heavy tasks at a time. (play a full 3D online game while extracting a 4GB RAR archive)

It freezes for about 200~500ms every few seconds, and this always happens if I do heavy tasks at once in my computer (for example, installing a program while playing games), and the lag remains permanently (even a reboot won't make it better) unless I repair-install the Windows.

Since I have a low-end computer:

- Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.00 GHz, 512 MB of RAM
- ATI RADEON 9550 AGP 256 MB

And the only way I used everytime to fix this problem is by repair-installing my Windows XP. So that I won't lose any data or installed programs.

But I believe there's a better and faster way to fix this without repair-installing the Windows.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any idea, what the computer is doing in this freezes? E.g. do you have a hard disk light that blinks in this time or a network connection light that blinks?

Answer (score 3):

with modern applications, 512 MB RAM is really the bare minimum, upgrade your system memory, RAM is cheap, 1 GB with XP is the minimum recommended these days, your board should be able to take 2 GB (check with the Memory Advisor tool at [www.crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/)).

weed out you startup routine with **[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)**.

at **[blackviper.com](http://www.blackviper.com/WinXP/servicecfg.htm)** you will find comprehensive service tweak guides.

last but not least, after the next 'fresh installation', create a drive image (i recommend [EASEUES Drive Copy](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/)). applying a 'clean' drive image of a pristine system is only a matter of minutes.

p.s.: extracting archives is one of the most demanding tasks. no surprise that it will bring your old system to it's knees while you're playing a 'full 3D online game".

Answer (score 0):

Use Game booster  http://www.iobit.com/